# Setting AcroField Position using iTextSharp

Tags: itext

The **iTextSharp** `AcroFields` class has a `GetFieldPosition` method.

I am attempting to modify a field's position programmatically. I'm wondering why there is no corresponding `SetFieldPosition`, or is there another way of changing a field's size or position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7099922/231316) for part of the reason. There isn't actually a singular `GetFieldPosition` but instead a plural [`GetFieldPositions`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/AcroFields.cs#l1566) since you can technically have multiple fields with the same name. So a theoretical `SetFieldPositions` would need to take this into account or it might erase some fields.

The other reason is that a field's defining areas aren't always that simple. Take this very simple bit of code:

```
var tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 400, 500, 500), "name");
writer.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField());
```

It creates a `400x100` text field with corners at `100,400` and `500,500`. It *also* creates an appearance entry `/AP` with a bounding box of `0,0` and `400,100` giving the normal appearance area that you see before clicking into the field. If you literally just changed the "position" by moving the two corners accordingly you'd be okay but since the position is really just a `Rectangle` there's nothing stopping you from making it wider or taller. In that case this `BBox` entry would need to get updated, too. This is a simple case and iText could probably work through it. Check boxes, however, usually have at least two appearance states that need to be altered. There could also be other cases that it might not make sense to propagate these changes through.

If you want to reposition a field, however, it can still be done, but the burden is on you to do it sanely. Imagine a simple PDF with just this single text field:

```
var tf = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 400, 500, 500), "name");
tf.Text = "Hi";
tf.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
tf.BorderWidth = 1;

writer.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField());
```

You can "move" the text field with a `PdfStamper` by getting the actual field and adjusting its `RECT` array. The code below.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None)) {
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(bytes)) {
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs)) {

            //Get our name field
            var nameField = reader.AcroFields.GetFieldItem("name");

            //Grab the first widget inside of it (there could be more)
            var w = nameField.GetWidget(0);

            //Grab the bounding array
            var r = w.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);

            //Check both of the Y values
            r[1] = new PdfNumber(r.GetAsNumber(1).IntValue - 300);
            r[3] = new PdfNumber(r.GetAsNumber(3).IntValue - 300);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "moving" is exactly what I needed to resize the fields.