# Repositioning Existing Signature Field

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to reposition an existing blank signature field in a PDF beneath content that has been added programmatically.  **I do NOT want to sign the document**...only to have a field for signing by other parties later.  I’ve tried numerous methods without any success.  None of my attempts yielded any change in the position of the field whatsoever.  The closest applicable post I found was: [Setting AcroField Position using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25328837/setting-acrofield-position-using-itextsharp) perhaps this method doesn’t apply to sig fields?

```
//Get our Sig Field
var SIG= pdfStamper.AcroFields.GetFieldItem("G4_Signature");

//Grab the first widget inside of it
var w = SIG.GetWidget(0);

//Grab the bounding array
var r = w.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);

//Check both of the Y values
r[1] = new PdfNumber(r.GetAsNumber(1).IntValue - 300);
r[3] = new PdfNumber(r.GetAsNumber(3).IntValue - 300);
```

Comment: Signature fields are annotations and are always on top of the content. There's no workaround.

Comment: *beneath content* - do you mean that on a z-axis, so that the content covers the signature field instead of the other way around? or do you mean that on the y axis, moving the signature field below the content so neither covers the other?

Comment: When I say "beneath" I mean below on the y-axis.  I guess I over-complicated what I am looking for.  I simply have and existing sig field in the PDF and I want to re-position on the page in the X and Y axis.  One thing covering another is not an issue.